# asp:checkedchanged event not firing?

Tags: asp.net

there. I have a gridview with a column of check boxes which was working when it was a small test project but when adding it to a page on my teams project it stopped firing the checkedChanged event. The check mark still appears or disappears but nothing fires. The only major difference is I was using an sqlDataSource object at first but for the new project i had to bind it to a database in the behind code.

Here's my html:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Create Incident">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Selections" runat="server" ViewStateMode = "Enabled" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and some simple behindcode:

```
  protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("clicked!");

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `AutoPostBack` to `True` to enable post back

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Selections" runat="server" ViewStateMode = "Enabled" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't fire either and it makes the checks disappear after a few seconds

Comment: It may be due to the GridView, can you post the code for the gridview, to see the properies you have set and I will update the code to reflect

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I added the conditional the block if(!page.isPostBack) around the stuff in my page load event.

Comment: yeah, take a look at the page lifecycle for an understanding of this. You can drop page from there too to shorten your code if `(!IsPostBack)`.

Answer (score 0):

Kept searching for about an hour till I found out that the actual reason why the OnCheckedChanged event was not firing on my page was due to duplication of names. Duh

An input control had a name 'submit' and there also exists a method in my JavaScript that is called submit(). The JavaScript interpreter was confused between the name of the control and a function, every time it needed to fire the event. Changed the name of the control and everything went back to working perfectly.